# Converting ThinkScripts CompoundValue Function to python

Tags: python, fibonacci, backtrader

```
declare lower;
def x = CompoundValue(2, x[1] + x[2], 1); 
plot FibonacciNumbers = x;
```

This is in thinkscript i want to convert this in python actually i am converting one of Thinkorswim  strategy in python backtrader

Comment: https://github.com/sureshja/ThinkOrSwim/blob/master/HeikinAshiSuperTrendStrategy.ts

Comment: did you find the Python equivalent for CompoundValue Function please?

Comment: I have implemented my strategy in Backtrader and BT has built-in CompoundValue please follow this this

https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2689/compound-value-calculation?_=1623244964765

Comment: Excellent Thank you. Have you automated TD Bot? Just curious may be we can bounce ideas.